# win 8 app call back handler - waiting on a runasync operation C++

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-async

I have a win 8 application written in unmanaged c++/cx which has a callback handler. The call back handler posts a notification to a UI thread.

I want to wait on the UI dispatch handler's background task.

I have the following code -

```
dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,lambda);
```

In the lambda, I update a view model that is bound to my view. I want to wait on this operation and check on the view model. Is it possible in unmanaged c++ ?? It is part of the unit testing that am doing on the app.

I found code references to achieve this in C#. I am not familiar with C++/CX to get this done. I would like comments on ideas to accomplish this. Thank you so much!

regards,
Varsha